# Braintree: Search transactions for subscription

Tags: braintree

I am currently implementing Braintree payments into my backend.

First off: I made the mistake and started implementing everything from Webhooks down. What I mean by that is that everything works as long as something does *not* work. In that scenario my backend would not be able to recover from certain situations. Simple example: Missing a webhook confirming a payment which triggers my billing routines.

Anyway, I am currently (partially) starting over. I want that my backend is always able to recover from missed webhooks. A fail safe, if you will, that does not get triggered as long as nothing breaks during webhooks or my server is down for more than 24 hours.

For this to work, I need to be able to synchronize the `Subscription` status as well as fetch all `Transactions`s. That's a must in order to be able to bill my customers correctly.

I am scheduling jobs which look at the `status` of a subscription, and let's say it is  `null` and it was created over 24 hours ago, my server will ask BT what is up with that subscription and update the result on my side.

So far so good, but I am struggling to find a way to reliably synchronize past transactions.

My idea was to store `last_transaction_date` in my `subscription` table and have another (scheduled) job compare that to `paid_throuth_date`. If the `last_transaction_date` was before `paid_through_date`, I want to fetch missing transactions for the affected subscription.

The problem with that part is, that it seems I cannot search for transactions for specific subscriptions:

```java
TransactionSearchRequest transactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequest()
        //.subscriptionId(subscriptionId) <-- Non existent?
        .createdAt()
        .greaterThanOrEqualTo(lastTransactionDate);
```

So what is the way to go here?

I don't think it's a good idea to just rely on webhooks - please tell me if I am too anxious about this but imho you never know whether your server might be down for more than 24 hours.

> **Info:** 24 hours is how long Braintree will try to reach your server and get a HTTP 200 response. After that it will stop sendind further webhooks.

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact at https://help.braintreepayments.com.

You can reference all of the past transactions via the transactions array in the subscription object: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription#transactions.

I am not sure what you are referring to as far as missing transactions, but this may be a better conversation with our Support team. Feel free to start a support ticket with us directly and we can assist you from there.

Comment: @bbusby Hello and thanks for the reply. The problem with `getSubscriptions()` is that it only contains the most recent transactions - that's why I thought it should be possible to fetch the entire history of a subscription somehow. I would not know how to to that at this  point. By "missing transactions" I meant that if my server is down for a longer period of time, it would miss webhooks and therefore transaction-notifications. In that case I want to "fetch missing transactions". :)